# How to stop numbers from automatically opening hyper links in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have ID numbers that I hyper link to a website. It's automatically hyperlinking the whole cell, preventing me from editing the text by double clicking the cell.

For example, let's say I have 7192023 in my cell, I right click the cell and enter in a hyperlink. I click Ok, and now anywhere I click in the cell, it automatically opens up a browser window. I want to avoid this.

Some things I have noticed is that if I enter in a letter, I am able to double click the white space in the cell to edit the cell contents. The icon here is a thick white cross icon, which is what I want.
I also have other cells that are hyperlinked with only numbers that do not have this issue, with the thick white cross icon, which is what I want.

The cells that are problematic have the mouse icon as the hand with the finger pointed.

Comment: You need to supply us with an example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So you want the whitespace in the cell to do nothing when you click it? If you expand the width of a cell with numbers in where you've added a hyperlink, to increase the white space, does it still click through?

Comment: I managed to replicate this. It's quite annoying, isn't it?

Comment: @spikey_richie Correct, even if I expand the cell, clicking the white space opens up the link to the browser.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to figure a way to stop it. The only thing i've found so far is to prefix the numbers with a letter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty crummy workaround is to prefix the numbers with `'`, to force it as a string rather than an integer/single/double type.

If I type `123` into a cell and add a hyperlink to superuser.com, your issue replicates.

If I type `'123` and add the hyperlink, I can click the whitespace in the cell without the link opening.

You can then ignore the warning

[image]

Comment: Very crummy workaround, I will accept though. I will opt to use in a # since these are numbers instead so at least it will make sense. Thank you!

Comment: If I find a neater solution, I'll update the answer. For me, adding a `#` automatically adds the `'` back in so you're no better off with `#`. It may be that some VBA is the only way to get round this problem, but that's a whole new world of pain.

Comment: P.S. Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if you believe it will meet your requirement (if somewhat clumsily).

Comment: What's interesting is that some other cells with just numbers + embedded hyperlinks do not have this issue. ):